# is "predatory capitalism" a correct word?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, terminology, translation, german

[Jean Ziegler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Ziegler) invented the German word **Raubtierkapitalismus** for huge companies without ethics and morality. For example Amazon, Google and Facebook.

What are similar words in English? Best would be a list, where I can choose from. I am not looking for historic terms. I am addressing the current issues (2018) with monopolies and capitalism.

I am mainly interested in words for technology enterprises (e.g. privacy violations), but also for traditional companies.

Found nothing in dict.leo.org for my question.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It would help to explain what you understand those concepts to mean and whether you are looking for a technical or a common term; there is almost certainly no single word that will fit. If needing to refer to Ziegler's concept specifically, I would simply use *raubtierkapitalismus* or *turbokapitalismus* as a loanword. *Turbo capitalism* outside of context sounds to me like a parody of a Marxist youth league brochure.

Comment: Per [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=predatory+capitalism%2Crampant+capitalism%2Cunbridled+capitalism&year_start=1945&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpredatory%20capitalism%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crampant%20capitalism%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunbridled%20capitalism%3B%2Cc0) for post-war relative preference, the front-runner collocation is ***unbridled capitalism***, which is more common than all instances with ***predatory*** and ***rampant*** put together.

Comment: this reads more like a political statement than an ELU question...

Comment: What did an online translator suggest?  (dict.leo is very good for German)

Comment: @FumbleFingers But this is why we need more context. On the one hand,  the historic period of *robber baron capitalism* might be what he's looking for, on the other, it might be theoretical ideologies like *anarcho-capitalism* (Rothbardist anarchism) . I don't trust Google Translate as far as I can throw it for translating philsophical terms.

Comment: You don't trust Google Translate, but I don't trust people telling me exactly what any given instance of *[**adjective**] **capitalism*** means. To a first approximation, *capitalism* simply is what it is - most such qualifications simply expose the speaker's / writer's *attitude* to capitalism, rather than meaningfully representing / identifying some specific real-world manifestation of the referent itself. As implied by Gary's comment above.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, but this is where things get contentious, because I would argue that *no* company has ethics or morality, not the hippiest organic kale collective, not the cutest bakery run by the sweetest grandmother. Only people can have such things, and people always have to make compromises to live in an ordered society, and that includes how they operate their enterprises.

Comment: @choster: Surely we're all three singing from the same hymn-sheet here. Capitalism is simply capitalism - an "abstract concept" that *certainly* doesn't have anthropocentric attributes like morality, ethics, wickedness, or whatever.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yep, agreed. My previous comment was only directed at the OP, but SE removed the @ tag.

Comment: @FumbleFingers that doesn't mean you can't look at it from different perspectives or theories and use different names to refer to those theories. As you say, such an adjective can be used to express one's attitude to capitalism. Maybe one wants to distinguish between two groups of *adjective1* and *adjective2* capitalism. In that case I think those adjectives are preferable over writing in full *those who subscribe to the theory that ...*

Comment: I really am an airhead. I saw Ziegler's name and completely forgot I know all about him. Ziegler writes in French; and the term in French he writes about is ***capitalisme prédateur***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Jean Zeigler is Swiss and writes in French**. He  uses the terme: capitalisme prédateur. I was thrown off by the German, I completely forgot about knowing about this sociologist. The term he uses **in French** is capitalisme prédateur.

From a book by him, L'Empire de la Honte (Empire of Shame), Fayard 2005, paperback reprint. p.18:

> Conclusion: il n'existe aucune fatalité, Un enfant qui meurt de faim
>   est assassiné.
>    L'ordre du monde économique, social et politique érigé par le capitalisme prédateur n'est pas seulement meurtrier. Il est aussi
>   absurde.

Translation:

> Conclusion: there is no inevitability here. A child who dies of hunger
>   is an assassinated child.
>   The order of the economic, social and political world erected by predatory capitalism is not only deadly. It is also absurd.

So, the German actually is what the French says. I'm leaving the German, but the French term capitalisme prédateur could be substituted for it.

Translation solutions used by professional translators for academic texts:

Solution One

*Raubtierkapitalismus* (predatory capitalism)

Solution Two

predatory capitalism (Raubtierkapitalismus)

Solution Three

predatory capitalism, Raubtierkapitalismus, [or the inverse] [with or without a footnote]

And there are other solutions, too. However, there is no doubt about predatory as it appears in two citations of academic works and is also a book by Noam Chomsky. So the notion is well established in English at a high register.

[predatory capitalism](https://books.google.com/books?id=yTpnDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=predatory%20capitalism%20Raubtierkapitalismus&source=bl&ots=jf7xLSPnNA&sig=6K1uQPayQ6rj8xXTIEF4pzuNUs8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj89rCwiZjcAhXng-AKHezEA7QQ6AEIUzAH#v=onepage&q=predatory%20capitalism%20Raubtierkapitalismus&f=false)

[predatory capitalism](https://books.google.com/books?id=u8VwuqyhqAwC&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=predatory%20capitalism%20Raubtierkapitalismus&source=bl&ots=AlqWEwQcMQ&sig=2K1T_gFGfmOF1gzI2nmJeBN58XI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj89rCwiZjcAhXng-AKHezEA7QQ6AEIWzAJ#v=onepage&q=predatory%20capitalism%20Raubtierkapitalismus&f=false)

Comment: I'm tempted to upvote this response just because its discussion of how to treat translations of complicated foreign terms in body copy is so sensible and clearly presented. But I'm not sure that it addresses the poster's central concern, which seems to be whether there is a better way to translate _Raubtierkapitalismus_ than as "predatory capitalism."

Comment: I do not think there is, and, I believe, two instances of it in academic texts and its being the title of a book are enough to show that.  There is also capitalisme sauvage, from the French, wild capitalism, which I reckon is how it might be translated into French....I see nothing wrong with predatory here in English for the German term. After all, that is what it actually means.

Comment: It's too bad we don't have the phrase "raptor capitalism" in English because that might suit the occasion. In any case, I think you're right: "predatory capitalism" hits the mark, is unambiguous, and has a presence in English already.

Comment: @SvenYargs I am modifying my answer. My head is really off these days. I know Zeigler's work quite well, he is not an economist, he is a sociologist and he writes in French!  le capitalisme prédateur

Answer (score 0):

When writing for a specialist audience whom you expect to be familiar with the term, I'd use **raubtier capitalism**. If they are not familiar I'd still use it but explain the term.

A similar, more widely used, term from Marxism is the German *Rentier-Kapitalismus*. That term is used in English as **rentier capitalism** (some examples: [Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2016/oct/26/the-corruption-of-capitalism-guy-standing-review-why-rentiers-thrive-and-work-does-not-pay), [economics professor writing for the OECD](https://www.oecd.org/naec/The_Precariat_under_Rentier_Capitalism_NAEC%209_Mar_17.pdf), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rentier_capitalism) and [Medium.com](https://medium.com/@herbstephens/airbnb-and-the-rotten-results-of-rentier-capitalism-3caeace75438)).

Another option is to translate to English and add the German in brackets:

> "predator capitalism" (Raubtier-Kapitalismus)

That's done in [this article by Eurofound](https://www.eurofound.europa.eu/is/observatories/eurwork/articles/vodafones-hostile-takeover-bid-for-mannesmann-highlights-debate-on-the-german-capitalist-model). This might be preferable if you don't really want to go into detail. The full term in German invites readers to Google the German term if they want to know more about it.

Comment: 'Rentier' sounds wrong. Also, wouldn't it be more naturally 'predatory capitalism'?

Comment: @Mitch that's the point if you choose to go with the German adjective. When writing for a less specialised audience (i.e. you want to avoid jargon) I agree that the fully translated term might be preferable. When writing for economists or scientists the German might be better (they are more likely to know the theory by its German name rather than one of a few possible translations). Another example is *[realpolitik*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realpolitik) which is used without translation [all the time](https://www.politico.com/search?q=realpolitik).

Comment: (Note: you’ve written *Rauptier* instead of *Raubtier* in the quote; too small to suggest an edit)